# Aggregate pipes together in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

So I have a giant pipe in my cascade that looks like this:

```
K1 - V1
K1 - V2
K1 -V3
K2 - V4
K2- V5
K2-V6
```

Is there anyway to aggregate them using an Every pipe such that the output looks something along these lines:

```
K1 - {V1, V2, V3}
K2 - {V4, V5, V6}
```

Thank you!

Edit:

My code so far:

I am calling the Every Pipe

```
    OutputPipe = new Every(OutputPipe, Fields.ALL, SomeBuffer());
```

And I am overriding the operate method in the buffer:

```
   @Override
    public void operate( FlowProcess flowProcess, BufferCall bufferCall )
    {
        TupleEntry group = bufferCall.getGroup();

        // get all the current argument values for this grouping
        Iterator<TupleEntry> arguments = bufferCall.getArgumentsIterator();
        // create a Tuple to hold our result values
        String result = "";
        String key = "";

        if (arguments.hasNext()) {
            TupleEntry argument = arguments.next();
            key = argument.getString("key") + "\t";
        }


        while (arguments.hasNext()) {
            TupleEntry argument = arguments.next();
            result += argument.getString("value") + "\t";
        }
        bufferCall.getOutputCollector().add(new Tuple(key, result));
    }
```

The output I get is kind of strange though. I keep getting strange results from reading in the file, so I'm guessing my logic in the every pipe is wrong.

Comment: There is many ways, but what do you tried so far ?

Comment: Currently I am using an Every pipe. I wrote my implementation in the comments under edit. :)